# How can I determine which connection is triggering an ATS block for cleartext HTTP?

Tags: ios9

Some ATS errors will display the actual URL that's causing a problem. However, seeing

`App Transport Security has blocked a cleartext HTTP (http://) resource load since it is insecure. Temporary exceptions can be configured via your app's Info.plist file.`

is not very helpful. Is there any way to register an app handler (or place some kind of global breakpoint) to figure out exactly which `HTTP` call is failing?

Setting a Symbolic Breakpoint for `NSLog` might work but I'm not sure how to filter the message to only break on output that begins with `App Transport Security`.

Answer (score 0):

One (non-code) option is to run a proxy (like Fiddler, Little Snitch, etc) and record whatever requests your emulator is making. You can then see what's `http` and whitelist it. I would still prefer a way to do this automatically in the app.